# creating a mysql table from a inner join

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I'm trying to create a mysql table from the inner join between two other tables. I'm dealing with a database someone creates which has the following tables:

- `sitematrix_sites`
- `sitematrix_databases`

They are related by another table (I don't know why don't use a foreign key) called `sitematrix_sites_databases` which has the following fields:
`site_id` and `database_id`.

That's how the two tables relate. Now I'm trying to remove that to make my life easier, so I have:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE result AS(select * from sitematrix_databases INNER JOIN site
matrix_site_databases ON sitematrix_site_databases.database_id = sitematrix_data
bases.database_id);
ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'database_id'
```

However, I'm getting that error. Does someone know how can I merge the two tables without repeating the `database_id` field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `*` in your SELECT statement and actually list out the columns you want in your new table. For columns that appear in both original tables, name the table as well (e.g. `sitematrix_databases.database_id`).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `*` instead name each column and use aliases. For instance instead of `sitematrix_database.database_id` you can have `alternativeName`. Also you can pick and choose which columns you want this way as well.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use "select into".  This might be equivalent syntax for mySql:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Unfortunately, it's a two commands (not just one):

- http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1487/copy-an-existing-mysql-table-to-a-new-table/

`CREATE TABLE recipes_new LIKE production.recipes; INSERT recipes_new SELECT * FROM production.recipes;`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `SELECT * ...` try `SELECT database_id ...`

MySQL does not like joining tables that have the same column name.