# create a new table from inner join result of 2 table

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I am stuck with some problems here.

I want to make a table that consisted of  some parts from other table, I have tried the solution mentioned in here:

[creating a mysql table from a inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040538/creating-a-mysql-table-from-a-inner-join)

and

[create a new table from a select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406245/create-a-new-table-from-a-select)

also some other questions in this forum
but none of them works for me.

So, my situation here is as the following:
I have 2 table:
1. tbl_student (inside this table there are student's id and their respective mark)
2. tbl_student_data (inside this table there are student's personal data)

these 2 tables have a relationship with tbl_data_siswa.student's id as the primary key and the tbl_siswa.student's id as the foreign key.

I know I can use the inner join to join the table according to my wish, but, these 2 tables are not permanent, it will be emptied yearly, so I need to make a backup of some field with its record from these 2 tables.

What should I do in this kind of situation?

Any kind of help is appreciated

Thank you!
(I'm sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Why do you have two tables? Why are they deleted, and of what relevance is that to your problem?

Comment: because that is what my supervisor asked me to do, he said something about the normalization of a database, as for why it is deleted, it is because the hardware here is limited, so I am afraid if the table's record is too much, then it will  load slowly, but I need to access the data from the previous year too, hence, I do it like this. @Strawberry , do you think there is more appropriate way to solve this problem?

Comment: I would definitely look at partitoning http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply, I am still green, so it really took me 2 days to understand about partitioning with the link that you gave me and some google search. And Thank you really, I will try using partitioning, it seems to be matching with what I need to do, I am not very clear about this yet, but I somehow got the vague idea what I need to do, So let me say thank you once more @Strawberry

Comment: Only 2 days? I *still* haven't figured it out :-p

Comment: Hey @Strawberry I must say thank you again, big help! it worked somehow. By the way, since I am still new to this forum, how can I mark your comment to be an answer? I don't see any button or guide for that?

Comment: Glad it helped. Just answer the question yourself, and accept that.